# Selenium driver is throwing an error while running the following script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html code:

```
<div class="leftpan-button leftpan-button-active" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Finalize'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Finalize">Finalize <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" ng-if="vm.statusCount.PendingCount"></span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --></div>
```

**Full div:**

```
Status list :<div class="panel-body tagList"><div class="leftpan-button leftpan-button-active" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Finalize'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Finalize">Finalize <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" ng-if="vm.statusCount.PendingCount"></span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --></div><div class="leftpan-button" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Pending for Approval'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Pending%20for%20Approval">Pending for approval <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-binding ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" ng-if="vm.statusCount.PendingCount" ng-bind="vm.statusCount.PendingCount">11</span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.PendingCount --></div><div class="leftpan-button" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Draft'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Draft">Upcoming <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.UpcomingCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-binding ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" data-ng-if="vm.statusCount.UpcomingCount" ng-bind="vm.statusCount.UpcomingCount">10</span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.UpcomingCount --></div><div class="leftpan-button" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Approved'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Approved">Approved <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.ApprovedCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-binding ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" data-ng-if="vm.statusCount.ApprovedCount" ng-bind="vm.statusCount.ApprovedCount">38</span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.ApprovedCount --></div><div class="leftpan-button" ui-sref="main.poList({status: 'Rejected'})" ui-sref-active="leftpan-button-active" title="" href="#/main/po/Rejected">Rejected <!-- ngIf: vm.statusCount.RejectedCount --><span class="badge pull-right ng-binding ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(255, 106, 0);" data-ng-if="vm.statusCount.RejectedCount" ng-bind="vm.statusCount.RejectedCount">9</span><!-- end ngIf: vm.statusCount.RejectedCount --></div></div>
```

I want to click on following Div, It is a link text.

I tried with a xpath,Css selector and link also, But I am getting following error:
I tried xpath as :

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='statusList']/div/div[1]").click();
```

CSS as:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#statusList > div > div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active")).click();
```

Link as:

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Finalize")).click();
```

Wait even as:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);// 1 minute
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.cssSelector("#statusList > div > div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active")));
```

Result:

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:261)
>     at com.example.tests.FinalizePO.main(FinalizePO.java:41) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#statusList > div
>
> > div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active"}   (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
> >     (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3
> >     x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
> >     information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds For
> >     documentation on this error, please visit:
> >     http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
> >     version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
> >     System info: host: 'admin', ip: '192.168.51.205', os.name: 'Windows
> >     8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
> >     [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
> >     mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459
> >     (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),
> >     userDataDir=C:\Users\BAYAPR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1612_1332},
> >     takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
> >     hasTouchScreen=false, version=50.0.2661.102, platform=WIN8_1,
> >     browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
> >     acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
> >     webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
> >     javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
> >     99a467e8f79b50f7c83ab694b88c2a75
> >     *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#statusList > div > div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active}    at
> >     sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> >     Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
> >       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)    at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:899)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:897)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
> >       at
> >     org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
> >       ... 1 more

Comment: as I see your HTM div has no id `statusList` present..

Comment: @Software_Engineer The element containing statusList would be a couple element higher up the tree.

Comment: Could you try this locator: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ng-if = "vm.statusCount.PendingCount"")).click();`. You might have to fix the quotations.

Comment: Now I added under full div,Please check.

Comment: Have you tried using **`contains`** with either `ui-sref` or `ui-sref-active` ...?

Comment: It is showing syntax error : driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ng-if = "vm.statusCount.PendingCount"")).click();

Comment: @bayaprakashreddy That's why I said you should fix the quotation. Replace `"vm.statusCount.PendingCount"` with `\"vm.statusCount.PendingCount\"`. It needs some escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 9);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active[href$='/main/po/Finalize']")));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.leftpan-button.leftpan-button-active[href$='/main/po/Finalize']")).click();
```

let me know what happens.

Comment: May I know, why 9000 ,I ran like 10 minutes back till now ,I did not get any response .

Comment: actually this will be 9 second, i already update my code...thanks

Comment: I got following errors: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[contains(text(),'Finalize')]. element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[contains(text(),'Finalize')]}

Comment: @bayaprakashreddy you are not paying attention to examine it's inside a frame or not... Be ensure it first...

Comment: @bayaprakashreddy, i already update my code but before running my code, do a thing manually, after loading the url and element, inspect the element in chrome browser, than search using ctrl+F, and paste my css selector and check how many suggestion it gives